# Conversion of simulink model into C code using code generation

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, toolbox

I need to know the various types of toolboxes available in simulink to convert simulink model into C code.

Is there any general steps to follow to convert the model into C? If there is any step, please do guide me.

Thanking you in advance for your valuable guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the products are [Simulink Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/), which requires [MATLAB Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/), and is used for generating C/C++ code from Simulink models to be used for rapid prototyping, hardware-in-the loop testing, simulation acceleration or simply an executable to be run outside of MATLAB and Simulink.

If you want to deploy the generate code on an embedded platform, customize or optimise the way the code is generated, you also need [Embedded Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/).

I suggest as a starting point, to watch the [videos](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/videos.html) on the Simulink Coder web page. Be aware though that code generation is a rather complex topic, for advanced users, and the tools are expensive.

Comment: Could I know the differences between Simulink Coder and Embedded Coder?

Comment: I have gone through the links which you have mentioned. But I could not know where to use these Simulink Coder blocks and Embedded Coder Blocks.

Comment: They are not "blocks" but tools that allow you to generate code. The videos explain how the basics of it work, but as I said, this is a fairly advanced topic to experienced users.